# Python - urllib2/wget/curl doesn't connect, Mac OS X

Tags: macos, curl, urllib2, firewall, wget

The original post is at the end.
I found out that this is not python specific but also curl/wget/telnet don't work.

I have now a partial solution: run everything as root....
i.e. sudo ipython and then run the example or sudo wget python.org

---

Hi,

I'm completely new to networks/python. I'd need to access a web page with urllib2 from my laptop (Mac Os X 10.6.6). I do this:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
```

What I get is either: 
**urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out**
(at home)
or
**urlopen error [Errno 51] Network is unreachable**
(at work).

I assume this is a problem with a firewall, unfortunately I can't figure out how to grant access to urllib2. I've allowed incoming connections for python/ipython/Python launcher in the firewall settings, but to no help...

My python is v2.6.1, urllib2 v2.6.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What firewall are you using? And are you behind some sort of proxy?

Comment: Should be an outgoing connection from the python/pythonw process, port 80. Knowing the firewall would be helpful.

Comment: It's just the standard Mac Application Firewall. I've just tried to disabling it completely and I still get the same result. I don't have any proxies set in the Network settings... I've tried wget and curl and they can't connect either... I can access my ftp with ncftp, though (generally no other problems accessing internet).

Comment: I have more: ping works OK. I've tried (from a similar thread): telnet python.org 80
Trying 2001:888:2000:d::a2...
telnet: connect to address 2001:888:2000:d::a2: No route to host
Trying 82.94.164.162...
Connected to python.org.  
I don't know exactly what this means, but I'd say port 80 is not working, but there is one that is working? Can I open 80 or set urllib2 to use the one available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a partial solution:

running everything as  root...

For now, it's OK, but if somebody knows how to solve this is, I'd still like to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Python, the problem is due to your routing or firewall configuration on your network.